# Record audio wtih trigger.io

Tags: trigger.io

I have seen that it's posible to play an audio through the media API's createAudioPlayer method. Is it possible to record an audio somwhow? Is there any API for it? Can I access de device's mike in any way and record with it?

Seems like I'm looking for something like Cordova's media.startRecord metgod on media API.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, no - we don't have implemented in one of our modules.

If it's something you need in a hurry, see our [native plugins](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/native/)!